# Method calling a the static singleton instance to call another method

Tags: c++

I'm browsing some random code and I found some confusing method, the class is a singleton,

```
class CFoo
{
   CFoo* _instance;
   CFoo(){};

public:
   ~CFoo(){};

   static CFoo* getInstance()
   {
       if(!_instance)
         _instance = new CFoo;

       return _instance;
   }

   static void deleteInstance()
   {
       if(_instance)
           delete _instance;
   }

   // just ordinary member method.
   void FooMethod()
   {
       CFoo::getInstance()->BarMethod(); //confusing..
   }

   // just ordinary member method.
   void BarMethod()
   {
      //code here..
   }
};

CFoo* CFoo::_instance = NULL;
```

Why FooMethod have to call the CFoo::getInstance() to call the BarMethod? Why not just calling BarMethod() directly?

Please advise.

Comment: I don't know. It would make sense if `FooMethod` were static.

Comment: Yes you are right, but FooMethod here is not a static method.

Comment: It may have been and this is left-over. where did this come from ?

Comment: Should really set `_instance` to `nullptr` after deletion. Also `CFoo* _instance;` should be static. Can also get rid of the `if` in delete

Answer (score 0):

If you call `CFoo::getInstance()->BarMethod()` within `CFoo::FooMethod()`, then the `this` keyword in the `BarMethod` refers to `CFoo::_instance`.

If you call `BarMethod()` within `CFoo::FooMethod()`, then the `this` keyword in the `BarMethod` refers to the same object on which `FooMethod()` was called.

It is not entirely clear whether there is effectively any difference. On the one hand, the only constructor that you implemented is private and you refer to the class as a *Singleton*. This supports the fact that only one instance of `CFoo` *should* exist, i.e. `this == CFoo::_instance` should always hold within `BarMethod`. On the other hand, `CFoo` has a public copy constructor, so `this == CFoo::_instance` might not always be true within `BarMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the  `FooMethod` and the `Barmethod` directly if you could create an object of this class. the problem is you can't do it because the construtor is private. the only way you can create the instance is using the `getInstance` method. and the method ensure it had no more than single object of this class.

**That's why it called singleton.**